# Generating rnorm() data within a range

Tags: r

How can I generate randomly distributed data within a rage of 10-15?
I tried this but, most of the data are just 10s.

```
library(MCMCglmm)

x=matrix(rtnorm(n = 100, lower = 10, upper = 15), nrow=10, ncol=10)
```

Here's a part of the matrix:

```
        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
 [1,] 10.01323 10.09077 10.12173 10.21363 10.14710 10.07159 10.19811 10.16515 10.14877 10.13405
 [2,] 10.10269 10.08853 10.07679 10.21932 10.15413 10.00907 10.00788 10.06476 10.06058 10.09998
 [3,] 10.00339 10.02658 10.05871 10.03135 10.07163 10.03250 10.08346 10.17975 10.10160 10.12360
 [4,] 10.00334 10.07949 10.00456 10.04519 10.11282 10.06135 10.05492 10.10164 10.13717 10.00696
 [5,] 10.12996 10.07651 10.25793 10.10667 10.14016 10.02615 10.02722 10.16351 10.28760 10.06861
```

As seen most of the data are 10s no 15s.

Comment: Which `rtnorm` are you using? There are **many** packages with the truncated normal distribution.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I'm using this package: `library(MCMCglmm)`

Comment: @RuiBarradas I will edit my question  better

Comment: can you explain why you completely changed your question? I answered your previous question; if that wasn't your real question, could you ask a new one? I'm tempted to roll back your edits ...

Comment: @BenBolker I did that because it wasn't precise enough

Comment: I can see how they're related, but it feels a little bit rude to change your question so much after an answer is already posted. I've given what I think is an answer to your new question, but it would really be **much** better in the future to post a new question (even if it's closely related) - you can link back to the previous question ...

Comment: @BenBolker yes you are right, I will try to find out how to roll back

Comment: @BenBolker I saw where my mistake was, so I will not post again that question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to change the mean to be in the middle of the range; it's zero by default.

```
library(MCMCglmm)
set.seed(101)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(rtnorm(1e5,lower=10,upper=15),col="gray",main="mean=0")
hist(rtnorm(1e5,mean=12.5,lower=10,upper=15),col="gray",main="mean=12.5")
```

[image]

In answer to your revised question, maybe

```
rtnorm(n, mean = x%*%beta+8, sd = 2, lower=10, upper=15)
```

will work.

Comment: I edited my question because it wasn't precise enough, I have an noise term still which changes the distribution